# Fullcalendar is shifting events one day back on some clients

Tags: fullcalendar

I am having a problem with fullcalendar displaying the events one day prior to the actual event.  In the image attached, all the "Place Order" events should be one day forward, from Mondays, Tuesdays, Wednesdays and Thursdays. Note these are individual events not one event. But on this client it is shifting them. <strike>I cannot reproduce the error on my machines and it only appears to happen on Mac.</strike> Any ideas? I have now been able to reproduce, it happens when the browser language is french. [image: Picture of rendered calendar]

Comment: Could be a timezone issue. No way of knowing without seeing relevant code and data. It's very unlikely to be related to a specific platform though. Please provide a [mre], thanks.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I would if I could, and this is my problem, I have only had clients let me know this is what they are seeing, I have not been able to reproduce the problem. I have tried changing the time zones, but I can still not personally reproduce the problem.

Comment: I appreciate it's not easy in these situations, but we can't have any more insight than you do, given the information available to us